# error python code: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, rospy

I'm all trying to pass a code from python2.7 to 3.8 but I'm stuck on the following code:

```
def serial_handle(self):
    # Serial initialization
    try:
        self.serial.reset_input_buffer()
        rospy.loginfo("Reaching for serial")
        rospy.loginfo("Here are the first 5 data readings ...")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.serial.reset_input_buffer()
        init_msg = self.serial.readline()
        for x in range(0, 5):
            #init_msg = self.serial.read(10)
            init_msg = self.serial.readline()
            rospy.loginfo( init_msg.encode('utf-8')[0:(len(init_msg)-1)] )
    except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
        rospy.logerr("Port timeout after %d seconds at: %s", self.timeout, self.device_port)
        self.serial.close
        sys.exit(0)
    
    # sent start signal
    self.serialOK = True
    self.serial.write( 'B'.encode('ascii') )
    time.sleep(0.08)        # for Arduino to reboot
```

because it always sends me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/paloverde/dev_ros_encoders/src/serial_odom/script/v0.3/serial_odom.py", line 95, in serial_handle
    rospy.loginfo( init_msg.encode('utf-8')[0:(len(init_msg)-1)] )
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Does anyone know what solution could be implemented for this?

Comment: Why are you calling `rospy.loginfo` with an encoded string?  It clearly expects a normal Unicode string as input.

Comment: What kind of data do you get from `init_msg = self.serial.readline()`? What kind of data is needed for `rospy.loginfo`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a byte string `init_msg` that you want to turn into a unicode string. You probably wanted to use decode instead of encode:

```
rospy.loginfo( init_msg.decode('utf-8')[0:(len(init_msg)-1)] )
```